# Excel vba variable not defined when using range variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have function **`testFunc`** that takes `Range` as an argument, loops thorugh its cells and edits them. I have sub **`testSub`** that tests **two cases**: first is when I pass the **current workbook's range** to **testFunc** through: **1. variable `Range` 2. just as an argument `testFunct(...Range("A1:A16"))`**.

The **second case** is when I open **another workbook** and do the same - pass one of its `worksheets` range to the **`testFunc`** **directly** or via **variable**.

```
Function testFunc(aCol As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each cell In aCol
        MsgBox (cell.Value)
        cell.Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next

    testFunc = i
End Function


Sub testSub()
    Dim origWorkbook As Workbook
    Set origWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A16")

    Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\vba\test_reserves\test_data\0503317-3_FO_001-2582480.XLS")
    Dim incomesNamesRange As Range
    Set incomesNamesRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A20")
   ' origWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(1, 5) = testFunc(dataWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("A1:A20"))

     origWorkbook.Worksheets("Ëèñò2").Cells(1, 50) = testFunc(incomesNamesRange)


  '  testFunc aRange
  'origWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(1, 5) = testFunc(aRange) '<---good
 ' origWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(1, 5) = testFunc(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A16"))
End Sub
```

The problem is, as I indicated with comments, when I open a foreign workbook and pass its range through a variable it gives an error `variable not defined`For Each cell In aCol`, while all other cases (including passing range variable of the current workbook) work fine.

I **need** `testFunc` to stay a `Function`, because it's a simplfied example of some code from bigger program which needs to take a returned value from a function. And I need to store that `Range` in a **variable** too, to minimize time of the execution.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, I replaced `Cells(1,5)` with `origWorkbook.Worksheet("shee t1").Cells(1,5)` and fixed variable name, but the original mistake changed to `variable not defined`. I edited the title and body of the question.

Comment: A `Workbook` object does not have a `Cells` property, so `origWorkbook.Cells(1, 50)` is not valid.  You need to specify which worksheet the `Cells`.refers to.

Comment: If you add `Option Explict` at the top all problem would have been resolved

Comment: ^^ Yeah, that too!!  (@ShaiRado Not **all** problems - the `Workbook.Cells` will still error.)

Comment: Re the edit to the question:  See Shai Rado's comment - using `Option Explicit` will show you the cause of the error.  Once you see it, it will take less than a second for you to fix it.

Comment: @YowE3K, Ok, I fixed it. There is still an error..

Comment: Having added `Option Explicit`, you should now define all your variables - e.g. `Dim cell As Range`.  That is good practice, even though it involves slightly more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default name for the worksheet shouldn't have a space in it.

```
Set incomesNamesRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A20")
```

Change this to:

```
    Set incomesNamesRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")
```

And see if that fixes it.